# How can I remove a style from the last item in a list?

Tags: css, height

I've just created something like this:

[image: Question]

Is there any way to remove the line from the end of the last colum? (it's a PHP while)

Code:

```
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 10px;">
            <div name="gameicon" style="width: 16px; margin-left: 5px; float: left;">
                <img src="images/games/<?php echo $games['short']; ?>.gif" alt="ICON" />
            </div>
            <div id="game" style="width: 115px; margin-left: 5px; float: left; text-align: right;">
                <b><?php echo $games['game']; ?></b>
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
                <?php echo $signs_count; ?>
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; margin-left: 3px; margin-right: 3px;">/</div>
            <div style="float: left; color: <?php echo $site_color; ?>;">
                <b><?php echo $signs_count_paid; ?></b>
            </div>
            <div class="clearer"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Which line? Can you show your PHP code?

Comment: The CSS for this particular table would probably be helpful too (if not more so).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: sorry, I answered before you edited in your code. This answer still applies, you would just have to change your HTML to place the div's in an unordered list.

You *could* use:

```
li:last-child div
{
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

However, some browsers do not support the `last-child` selector (IE7, for example). There is more support for the `first-child` selector. One option you do have is to add that border to the top of the elements instead of the bottom, and then remove that border from the top instead, using:

```
li:first-child div
{
    border-top: 0;
}
```

---

Another option is to use jQuery to alter the CSS, so you know it will work cross-browser:

```
$('#yourUL > li:last-child > div').css('border-bottom','0');
```

Comment: Should I put them to <ul><li>etc. ?

Comment: Yes, each div will go inside of a `<li>`.

Answer (score 1):

what if you change your code , first line from :

```
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 10px;">
```

To :

```
<div class="mainDiv">
```

CSS:

```
.mainDiv { 
    border-top: 1px solid #cdcdcd; 
    margin-right: 10px; 
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px; 
    font-size: 10px;
}

.mainDiv:first-child { 
    border: 0;
}
```

I hope this way will be helpful.